# WPML to exclude particular ACF fields from translating

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I am creating a page in WordPress that contains acf fields such as: company name, address email etc

This page needs to be translated into 9 different languages. For this I'm using wpml.

Is there a way that I can specify for wpml to NOT translate a particular act field such as the company name?

For example if company name is 'forever young' I don't want company name to turn to another language.

I have done much research but can't find any solution to this. Can somebody help?